# pygame platform game jumping code not doing as expected

Tags: python, sprite

For my a-level coursework I am creating a game and I am struggling getting my sprite to jump. Its hard to explain what is happening but I will try my best. When I press the up arrow which is my jump button the sprite appears higher instead of smoothly jumping and then falls and I think it only falls because of the gravity feature I have implemented.

This is the section of code specifically that is not working, I have only tried to add the feature in for my first sprite so far so its mainly the section I've highlighted with hashtags

```
def level1():
    global running, jumping1
    global x1, y1 , x2, y2, xChange1, yChange1, xChange2, yChange2, jump1, jump2, jumping1, jumping2, isJump

    while running:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    xChange1 = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    xChange1 = 5
###############################################################################
                if not jumping1:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        jumping1 = True
                else:
                    if jump1 >= -25:
                        y1 -= (jump1 **2) * 0.5
                        jump1 -= 1
                    else:
                        jump1 = 10
                        jumping1 = False
##############################################################################
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    xChange1 = 0


            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    xChange2 = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    xChange2 = 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    yChange2 = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    yChange2 = 5
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    xChange2 = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    yChange2 = 0           

        x1 += xChange1
        x2 += xChange2
        y1 += yChange1
        y2 += yChange2

        y1 -= gravity1
        y2 -= gravity2
        
        screen.blit(game_image,(0,0))
        character1(x1,y1)
        character2(x2,y2)
        gameFloor(fx,fy)

        if x1 < 0:
            x1 = 0
        if x1 > WIDTH - Char1WIDTH:
            x1 = WIDTH - Char1WIDTH

        if y1 < 0:
            y1 = 0
        if y1 > HEIGHT - Char1HEIGHT - 50:
            y1 = HEIGHT - Char1HEIGHT - 50

        if x2 < 0:
            x2 = 0
        if x2 > WIDTH - Char2WIDTH:
            x2 = WIDTH - Char2WIDTH

        if y2 < 0:
            y2 = 0
        if y2 > HEIGHT - Char2HEIGHT-50:
            y2 = HEIGHT - Char2HEIGHT -50


            
        pygame.display.flip()
```

I'm not sure if you can put links but I have made a link to my whole code as I think its too long to include in a post: https://trinket.io/python/189549b1dd

Answer (score 0):

You should not put your jumping part inside the pygame.event loop, because then it will only function if you press the key again. Instead

```
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    if not jumping1:    
                        jumping1 = True
```

then put the jumping function somewhere in the main loop, but not in the `pygame.event.get()`loop

```
               if jumping1:
                    if jump1 >= -25:
                        y1 -= (jump1 **2) * 0.5
                        jump1 -= 1
                    else:
                        jump1 = 10
                        jumping1 = False
```

it should be fine